# bootstrap, padding in head element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

Can anyone tell me why in the world Initializr's bootstrap html template has a single style for body in a  element in the head of the page? It's right after the bootstrap.css file.

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

My question is: isn't it a little odd to throw a one-off style directly in the markup and not just include it in the bootstrap.css file?  Is there some specific reason anyone knows of as to why it was done this way?  CSS belongs in CSS files, no?

Comment: what are you trying to say? take a coffee and re-phrase your question :)

Comment: yikes! maybe it's due to the espresso i just wolfed. editing the post.

Comment: Ok, stackoverflow fail on my part. The answer is probably that this snippet is the only style that exists in in the 'jumbotron.css' file that accompanies Bootstrap's Jumbotron example, which is what the Intializr Bootstrap boilerplate is based off. It's specific to a 50px-tall navbar that overlays the Jumbotron. It looks like whoever wrote the Intializr template thought it best to just plop this style element in the head, as opposed to mucking with bootstrap.css, and instead of including the jumbotron.css file. Not sure why that's a best practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look I would assume because it relates to that page specifically.

What if on another page you didn't want the navigation bar? You then have to override the style implemented in the .css file manually to correct the padding. Seeing as it's only one statement, I'd say it's fair to include it at the top of the page rather than putting it in it's own .css file.

Would you really want to obscure a framework .CSS file by including potentially page-specific code (that would muddy the framework)?

Edit: To elaborate - if you have a rigorous structure across dozens of pages, each with consistent style, it would only make sense to centralise this content into a .css file, however from an industry perspective I would more-than-likely still not put it into a framework .css file (think about future implementations, upgrading the framework, versioning etc etc).

Comment: Definitely agree that it doesn't belong in the bootstrap.css file, now that I realized this was a template generated by Initializr, and that the style was specific to the "Jumbotron" layout. However Bootstrap's inclusion of the style in a separate jumbotron.css file seems like a better option.  I think I'd namespace the whole page by placing a "jumbotron" class on the body tag, when it contained this jumbotron feature, and just have a body.jumbotron declaration in main.css...  I was just all-around confused earlier.

Comment: That is entirely sound reasoning, but I think the way it's implemented in the template is fine too: a single .html with custom CSS declared at the top is simple and effective; creating a stylesheet file for this reason would seem overkill just as putting it in the markup seems - for lack of a better word: lazy.

Comment: Yeah, I guess what gets me is the main.css file is just sitting there empty in the generated project scaffolding...  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this and just about eliminated my Initializr foundation because:

**A)** The Initializr index.html rendered differently from the same page on [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) and I could not figure out why

**B)** It was not at all obvious why this style was inline inside the `<head>` section since there was no comment.

Thankfully I did not delete the Initializr files. It turns out [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) includes these same styles (but via a very small stylesheet named ***theme.css***). The values are a bit different than the ones you mentioned, but same idea.

The theme I was referencing included this ***theme.css***:

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.theme-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.theme-showcase > p > .btn {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.theme-showcase .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
```

So, long story short- Initializr did the right thing here by removing the extra include in my opinion... HOWEVER, a `<!-- Comment -->` explaining what those styles are should be there. There are comments on most sections, yet none for this snippet.

Anyways, I am keeping my beautiful Initializr Bootstrap code base, and figuring out what pages need what values of what snippets lol.